# Bayesian Forecast: Credible interval with predicted regressors

Tags: time-series, bayesian, forecasting, credible-interval

I want to do a forecast of let's say orders with a Bayesian linear regression, where orders do not only depend on time but also on another regressor, let's say accounts at time t.
$$orders_{t} = \theta_{1}*t + \theta_{2}*accounts_{t} + \epsilon$$
So obviously, I do not have future values of accounts, so when predicting future values of order intake I use a prediction of accounts
$$accounts_{t} = \beta_{1}*t + \epsilon$$
Now, for predicted accounts I can construct a credible interval as it only depends on known and fixed values (time). For predicted orders, uncertainty around the account prediction carries over into the prediction, so a credible interval for the order prediction would need to take this uncertainty into account. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In Bayesian Inference the prediction step is done via the *posterior predictive* distribution, which is calculated as $$f(y_{new} | y_{(\underline{n})} ) = \int_{ \Theta} f(y | \theta ) \cdot \pi(\theta ) d \theta $$ (where $\pi(\theta)$ is the posterior distribution) which accounts for the uncertainty of and unobserved observation.